# How can I make a often shop?

Tags: discussion

Since you are not logged in right now, you will be asked to sign in or register after posting your question? What can I do?

Comment: Sign in or register?

Comment: What do you mean? If you are asked to sign in, just sign in/up.

Comment: "often shop"???

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Oscillation

Comment: @Bart yeah, looks like it's spreading!

Answer (score 3):

There are two possibilities:

- If you have an account:  sign in.
- If you don't have an account: register.

If you have an account, but you are not able to sign in, call for support.